# Do males commonly use lubricant for masturbation?

Tags: sexuality, masturbation

As often seen in Hollywood movies, a bottle of lube (or oil or anything) is something one would always prepare for masturbation.

I'll spare you the detail, but as a European I'm, um, not quite accustomed to this practice.

A quick search on Wikipedia seems to confirm the claim is notable:

> While most males and females both produce varying amounts of their own lubrication, it is often desirable to add extra lubrication. There are specific lubricants which may be used in male masturbation but are not suitable for vaginal or anal use or for use with condoms.  Lubricant that is safe for sexual intercourse is also safe for masturbation.
>
> Masturbation cream is specially formulated to enhance male masturbation.

-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_lubricant#Masturbation

Is it a movie cliche or Americans do use it more often than Europeans?

Comment: I've added a notability example.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that male circumcision is more common in North America than in Europe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Global_Map_of_Male_Circumcision_Prevalence_at_Country_Level.png (pardon my Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

Male masturbation lubricants are fairly mainstream on Amazon.com.

For example this personal lubricant is clearly marketed for male masturbation and it's one of the top 100 personal lubricants on Amazon.com:

[image: Personal lubricant ranking]

<sup>[source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/10786421)</sup>

This is the highest seller among the [three masturbation creams mentioned by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation_cream#cite_note-1) as being in common use.

Comment: does not answer the question. Just because something exists, does not mean it's used much, let alone "commonly".

Comment: Looking at sales is not indicative of usage? I disagree @jwenting

Comment: it's not. You don't know how many people are responsible for those sales, what percentage of the total potential customer base (male masturbators) that is. Plus you don't have actual sales numbers at all, only "sales ranking" which is a relative number. Even if Amazon sells 1 million units a year, if they sell those to 10000 people, that's only a tiny percentage of the world population of men engaging in auto erotic stimulation.

Comment: @jwe we can say that that they are as popular as the other items in this category, after all that's what the top sold items list is for. The OP doesn't ask for absolute figures: I am simply showing that it is a relatively common item. What would a number accomplish? Knowing how many sales amazon does is only relevant in comparison with other amazon sale figures: we wouldn't know what percentage of masturbation lubricant users buy lubricant on amazon either.